# Putting a plug socket on a cable which was previously wired into a heater?

Tags: wiring

Can someone please tell me if the following is safe?
I have a faulty electrical heater which is wired into a switch on the wall. I am trying to replace the heater as simply as possible. Is it possible to simply fit a plug socket to the cable,then plug a heater into this? This option seems simpler than wiring the cable into a new heater? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and what type of *cordage* was used for the connection between the wallbox and the heater?

Answer (score 2):

SMH how is that simpler??

You get a new heater of the same basic form-factor, bolt it up in the old location, and connect the wires to it like it was to the old one.

Clearly the skill to attach wires is not absent, since you plan to wire it to a receptacle.

Do you possibly have a mental block about "gosh, I don't know where to get one of those" or "surely they must be expensive"?  Home Depot, and $50-100 depending.

I know it's not at the top of your list of things to spend $100 on this week, but life happens.  You'll be getting something that'll last 20 years, as opposed to those little plug-in heaters that won't last a season if they're your primary heat. You could easily spend more on junky little heaters than you do on the proper one.

Further, the proper one is surely 240V -- and that means you'll need to use a NEMA 6 receptacle, and you'll be paying a lot for weird heaters. You could buy a $50 Cadet made-for-permanent-installation heater and put a cord on it, but why not just permanently install it?

At best, a plug-in heater isn't going to be *cheaper enough* to justify the trouble.  Might as well just do it right.

Answer (score 0):

A lot more information about the wattage of the new heater, breaker size, etc. would be needed to thoroughly answer this. In a nutshell though,if the instructions for the new heater state that it can be installed with a cord and plug then you could and would then need to add the appropriate electrical box and outlet to the wires from the switch. If the instructions state that the heater needs to be hard wired, then so be it.